# Magento 2: Print packing slips without shipment

Tags: magento2, print, packing-slip

I want to print packing slips without creating shipment and when order status is 'processing'.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, for printing packing slip you need the shipment instance (source for printing)

You can create correct shipment instance with all related data and just use `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Shipment` and pass shipment without save it

**Note:** You should understand that you will not have a valid increment id and you will have empty string in document like `Packing Slip #`